# Construct3 game into an ionic application

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ajax

i have a construct3 game to integrate into  an ionic  application. I want that application and construct3 game are working together and use Ajax for external api. Finally ,i will compile into apk. Is it possible?

Comment: So it's not interesting to do this ... I used **Cordova** because the overlay Ionic UI is not necessary